# Not able to login after SAML2 setup with ATTASK (Workfront) using ADFS IDP

Tags: spring, saml-2.0, spring-saml, attask

I am integrating Workfront(Attask) with my web application. I have configured SAML2 setting inside Attask setting tab and uploaded my Attask SP Metadata to IDP and IDP metadata to SP successfully. When I tried to test connection with given setting Saml token response was getting populated with ADFS attributes.  However I selected checkbox for user-provisioning and mapped given attributes with Attask.

When I try to login using IDP url it was coming to attask login page with error.
url error:
    login?arg0=mercatus2.attask-ondemand.com&ssoError=exception.sso.saml2.domainnotconfigured

login screen erorr

```
Let's try that again.
SAML configuration not present for mercatus2.attask-ondemand.com
```

I am not sure whether this error is coming because my domain is not present for Workfront or is there any other reason??

Comment: this only happens when you try to connect using IDP initiated? are you able to connect using SP initiated?  When you go to setup > system > customer info is their a value listed under domain?

Comment: @michaeljohnson you are right I am able to access using SP but when I try using IDP then it gives the above error. I have checked the customer info for domain value. domain = mercatus2

Comment: @michaeljohnson  I have tried many combination but no luck. can you please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the enabled checkbox checked within the SSO setup within workfront?

Comment: Thanks Michael, Yes I am able to login after selecting this check box. However I am not able to login using SP initiated SSO with below URL.
https://mercatus2.attask-ondemand.com/saml/login

I am getting this error message...
No IDP was configured, please update included metadata with at least one IDP

Comment: I would suggest calling workfront support we can then dig deeper into the problem with screenshots of your setup. and do a scheduled call if needed.